# Two machines returning a different encoding result for the same file

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I am running the below code on two different machines with the same file, but each one is returning a different character encoding type:

```
def encoding_type
 File.read(file_path).encoding.name
end
```

Does that make any sense?

Comment: I'm guessing an answer of "yes" or "no" isn't what you are looking for?  What platforms are these machines?  What Ruby versions?  Was the file checked out from a version control system that may alter file encodings?

Comment: Both machines are CentOS. Both machines are using the same version of Ruby, 1.9.3. The file was not checked out from a version control system. Exact copy on each machine.

Comment: If the files are older than a few seconds (i.e. you have not copied the file specifically to test this), it is also worth verifying "exact copy" with a checksum, e.g. MD5 or SHA1. But one very likely cause is that the two Ruby installations have different default external encodings . . . generally Ruby doesn't "detect" encoding, it "assumes" it, and *you* have to tell it what to assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the two machines are using different default encodings. You can verify this by inspecting the return value from `Encoding.default_external` - it should match the two different encodings you get from your `File.read( file_path )`. If you were assuming the given file somehow declared its encoding in a way that Ruby detected, you were most likely wrong - it is possible for Ruby to determine correct `String` encoding in some scenarios, but reading a file from disk is not one of them. In fact many encodings are not technically distinguishable from the file alone, and although it is possible to have a good guess that is not something you should expect from any language's basic file reading library.

The [documentation on Encoding.default_external](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Encoding.html#method-c-default_external) explains where it applies. It includes file reads where you have not specified the file encoding.

One possible root cause is different locale settings on each machine.

The best fix will vary depending on what your code needs to do. One simple fix, if you want your application to use consistent encoding everywhere and ignore machine settings, is to just set the value:

```
Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'
```

Another option, if the problem is specific to this file, and you want to use machine settings elsewhere in your app is to open the file with a specific encoding:

```
File.read(file_path, :encoding => 'UTF-8')
```

You could also alter the locale setting on the two machines, if that makes sense for other uses the two machines have.